# getting no return data on notification url from paypal in adaptive paypal chained payment

Tags: cakephp, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using chained method of adaptive payment:
params are like this:

```
$bodyparams = array("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
            "actionType" => "PAY",
            "currencyCode" => "USD",
            "cancelUrl" => "www.example.com/courses/cancelPurchase/", 
            "returnUrl" => "www.example.com/courses/buyCourse/" . $courseId . "/" . $courseDetails['Course']['certificate_amount'], 
            "receiverList.receiver(0).email" => $adminDetails['paypal_email'], 
            "receiverList.receiver(0).amount" => round($courseDetails['Course']['certificate_amount'], 2), 
            "receiverList.receiver(0).primary" => "true",
            "receiverList.receiver(1).email" => $courseDetails['UsersRole']['User']['paypal_email'], 
            "receiverList.receiver(1).amount" => $courseCreatorAmount, 
            "receiverList.receiver(1).primary" => "false", 
            "ipnNotificationUrl" => "www.example.com/courses/ipnReturn", 
        );
```

Here I am not getting  any data on **ipnNotificationUrl** provided.
It seems that after returning from paypal it is not at all hitting this url.

Please help!!

FYI: I am using cakephp as framework.

Comment: how is the array in your question being used ...? What exactly is the (code) problem?

Comment: I am not able to get success or failure or anything on  "ipnNotificationUrl" => "www.example.com/courses/ipnReturn" .. it seems after returning from paypal it is not hitting this url to send me response array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have IPN's turned on in the account? Should be under Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Instant Payment Notifications.

Make sure this is turned on.

If it is, contact http://www.paypal.com/mts and ask them to look at the IPN history and see if there they can find any reason why this is not working properly.

Comment: Slight correction; you can find your own IPN History by logging into www.paypal.com > History > IPN History. (Note: this will only work if IPN is set to 'On' inside your PayPal account). This will display the HTTP response code for attempting IPN messages (if any).